# Probability distribution for number of concurrent events

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

Say we have a type of event that lasts 30 seconds and occurs on average once per second.

I know that you can use an exponential distribution to describe time between events, or a Poisson distribution to describe how many events start in a fixed period. What distribution describes the variable "number of events simultaneously occurring"? I would like to answer questions like:

- "What is the mean number of events simultaneously occurring?"
- "During what proportion of time are more than two events co-occurring?" (i.e., $P(x > 2)$)

Is there also an answer if the duration is a distribution instead of fixed?

**Edit:** [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2410179/923124) seems to answer my question, but only for durations with an exponential distribution.

Comment: For the first question: If the length of each event is deterministically 30 seconds, then the number of events simultaneously occurring at a given time $t$ is equivalent to the number of events that started in the time interval $[t-30, t]$, which is Poisson with mean $30$.

Comment: Wow, that's really simple. Thank you.